# Sort array based on startDate

Tags: meteor, meteor-autoform

I'm trying to sort an array and not having much luck. If I remove the `helper` I print out the all the qualifications in the order they went into the database. I would like to display them chronologically based on their `startDate`.

Path: `dbExample`

```
"profile": {
    "CV": {
      "education": [
        {
          "qualification": "Arts Degree",
          "startDate": "2009-01-01T00:00:00.000Z",
          "endDate": "2013-12-01T00:00:00.000Z"
        },
        {
          "qualification": "Science Degree",
          "startDate": "2007-01-01T00:00:00.000Z",
          "endDate": "2008-12-01T00:00:00.000Z"
        }
      ]
    }
}
```

Path: `education.html`

```
<template name="education">
    {{#each educationHistory}}
    <div class="box">
        <p class="title">{{qualification}}</p>
        <p class="dates">{{startDate}} - {{endDate}}</p>                
    </div>
    {{/each}}
</template>
```

Path: `education.js`

```
Template.education.helpers({
    educationHistory: function () {
        return Meteor.users.find({}, {sort: {"startDate": 1}});     
    }
});
```

Path: `Schema.js`

```
Schema.Education = new SimpleSchema({
    qualification: {
        type: String,  
        optional: true    
    },
    startDate: {
        type: Date,  
        optional: true 
    },
    endDate: {
        type: Date,  
        optional: true  
    }
});

Schema.CV = new SimpleSchema({
    education: {
        type: [Schema.Education],
        optional: true
    }
});
```

Comment: How are users and CVs related? Showing the simple schema has become popular in questions lately, but I find showing an example document to be more helpful.

Comment: Hi David. Excuse my noob question, but when you say example document are you referring to the mongoDB. If so how do you recommend I write it up?

Comment: If that's what you meant I've added an mongoDB example that I pulled from meteortoys. I hope that's what you wanted.

Comment: Yep, that's what I needed - I'll have an answer in a minute.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a little hard to follow because I don't know the context of the template or which user's education history to use. Here are a couple of solution ideas:

**solution 1**

```js
Template.education.helpers({
  educationHistory: function () {
    // replace Meteor.user() with Meteor.users.findOne(someId) or something
    const { education } = Meteor.user().profile.CV;
    return _.sortBy(education, e => e.startDate);
  },
});
```

This returns an array of education objects, sorted by `startDate`.

**solution 2**

If the template already has an `educationHistory` without the helper (based on your comments below), then you can replace the `educationHistory` helper with this:

```js
Template.education.helpers({
  sortByStartDate: function (education) {
    return _.sortBy(education, e => e.startDate);
  },
});
```

Then in your template:

```html
<template name="education">
  {{#each sortByStartDate educationHistory}}
    <div class="box">
      <p class="title">{{qualification}}</p>
      <p class="dates">{{startDate}} - {{endDate}}</p>
    </div>
  {{/each}}
</template>
```

Comment: Thanks David, when I use this it prints out a single date multiple times with no other info. Is there something wrong with my handlebars?

Comment: That needs to be fixed as well. Arg, I think I still may not be understanding the question... So do you want all of the education histories for all users, or just the history for a single (the current?) user?

Comment: For a single user. Its referencing an ID in the URL. This is a second template being referenced in. If I remove the helper completely it works, it just doesn't sort. Does that make sense?

Comment: Maybe. It's a little hard to follow because I don't know the context of the template. If it works w/o the helper then the template already has an `educationHistory` in the context.

Comment: See the updated answer. Maybe one of those will work.

Comment: Thanks David. Worked a treat!